# Cognito documentation by AWS seems to be nonsensical

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to allow my users to go through a forgot password flow for their Cognito User Pool account in my Javascript swebsite.

As User Pools are in their beta some of the documentation is lacking, and in this case bizarre. AWS make the claim that the following code should:

> starts and completes a forgotten password flow for an unauthenticated user.

with the code being:

```
cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('call result: ' + result);
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        },
        inputVerificationCode() {
            var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code ' ,'');
            var newPassword = prompt('Enter new password ' ,'');
            cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, this);
        }
    });
```

Can anyone make sense of this code, or at least confirm/deny that it is seemingly nonsensical?

It can be found at the following link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html

Comment: Maybe this would be best brought to AWS' attention directly through their user forums.

Comment: I have only tried posting to their developer forums a few times and no one ever replied which put me off using them, but perhaps I should try again.

Comment: What's the specific problem you see?  Is it syntactically valid?  Have you tried it?  It seems like the verification code would be sent from cognito infrastructure, so it must come through another path -- such as the user's email or phone number through SMS, maybe?

Comment: The documentation for "user pools" is severely lacking and confusing in my view too. However, saying something is nonsensical, without saying what it is about it that you find nonsensical is unlikely to get you useful answers — some people will reply with "makes perfect sense" (perhaps) other will agree with you. Either way, it won't get you any further. Is the problem that there isn't enough code there for a complete working example? Is it that you're expecting a proper GUI flow (which isn't provided by User Pools, that's your job)? If it's any conselation I feel your pain!

Answer (score 1):

The stuff with the prompts in the examples are indeed a bit odd. You'd probably want to do this differently. You can actually call confirmPassword separately by getting the current cognitoUser from localstorage after initiating the forgotPassword process and then call cognitoUser.confirmPassword

You can get the current cognitoUser like this:

```
var data = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_Iqc12345', // Your UserPoolId
        ClientId : '12345du353sm7khjj1q' // Your client ID
    };
    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(data);
    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
```

And then you can call

```
cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, {
     onSuccess: function(result){
         // Do stuff on success
     },
     onFailure: function(err){
         // Do stuff on error
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The example should work. It works on an unauthenticated, confirmed user so once your pool and user name data is setup you can run the example. The forgotPassword function calls the relevant callbacks upon failure, success, or to request the new password and verification code information.

```
var poolData = {
    UserPoolId : 'YOUR_USER_POOL_ID',
    ClientId : 'YOUR_APP_ID'
};

var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username : 'YOUR_USER_NAME',
    Pool : userPool
};

var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);

cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('call result: ' + result);
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },
    inputVerificationCode() {
        var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code ' ,'');
        var newPassword = prompt('Enter new password ' ,'');
        cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, this);
    }
});
```

What is the part that doesn't make sense so we can improve the documentation after the public beta? Is the flow incorrect or some information is missing?